# Solving modular congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following equation:
$$-16 \equiv b \pmod {26}.$$

How do I calculate the value of $b$? I have forgotten elementary maths and want to refresh my concepts. Please explain to me how to solve the above equation.

Comment: $b$ can be $-16,10,36,62,88,$ etc. Modulo is an equivalence relation consisting of classes having infinitely many members each, and there are infinitely many integers $b$ can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-16 \equiv b \pmod {26}\tag{1}$$
means that
$$-16 =26k+b,$$
for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, hence
$$b=26h-16,$$
for some $h=-k\in\Bbb Z$.
So, the (integer) values for $b$ to satisfy $(1)$ are those (and only those) in the set
$$\{b\ |\ b=26h-16,\ h\in\Bbb Z\}=\{\ldots,-42,-16,10,36,\ldots\}$$

($b=-42,-16,10,36$ here respectively correspond to $h=-1,0,1,2$).